# How to synchronize CRM for Phone with CRM 2016 Online Update 1

Tags: android, ios, ipad, synchronization, dynamics-crm-online

I've requested a Demo CRM Online environment to test the FieldOne Solution. I've successfully synchronized the CRM with the FieldOne Sky app, but I am requested to synchronize the CRM with the native CRM for Phones app and display the custom entities from the FieldOne Solution on the app.

The problem is that when I try to synchronize it with CRM for Phone Express I get the message:

"There's a newer version of the app available. Would you like to check it out?"

And if I try to synchronize it with the CRM for Phones, I am shown only the standard entity types (even though I've marked the FieldOne entities properties "Enable for phone express" and "Enable for mobile").

I tried the app on both an Android and an iPad devices and the message is still displayed.

Where could be the reason for me not being able to synchronize with CRM for Phone Express, or not seeing the custom entities on CRM for Phones?

Thanks.

Best regards,
Evgeni Dyulgerov